# What might cause my events system not to "fire" when events take place?

Tags: event-system

I have the following code, which is as generic an events system as you could imagine. When it's deployed, and I attach a debugger to the process, when an event takes place I can see the assembly getting loaded into the process, with symbols, but the code appears not to execute, and I can't get a breakpoint to bite. What am I missing?

```
[TcmExtension("FoobarEventsSystem")]
class Events : Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension
{
    public Events()
    {
        EventSystem.Subscribe<IdentifiableObject, TcmEventArgs>(
                      Handler, EventPhases.All, EventSubscriptionOrder.Normal);
    }
    private void Handler(IdentifiableObject subject, TcmEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("foobar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make the class public:

```
public class Events : Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. Obvious when you know the answer. :-)